# Hide span with jquery is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a sharepoint webpart that shows some information from some lists, the lists are security trimmed, so if the user does not have permission to that list, it will show access denied. Which is fine.

I want to hide that part of the page.

I found how to solve it here:
http://www.timferro.com/wordpress/archives/227

This is the code I have:

```
<script src="/_layouts/Scripts/jquery1.8.1.min.js"></script><script language="javascript">


$("span:contains('Error')").hide();
$("div:contains('Access denied'):not(:has(div))").hide();</script>
```

And this is the screenshot that shows what I need to hide.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKh7p.png)

Better pic here

[image]

**Update:**
when I hide it, now sharepoint its showing me a blue line that I want to get rid off, but If I hide the blue line only, then a strange space will be between webparts, I think the best is to hide that TD that contains the rest of the things? How can I hide that?

Please see new screeenshot

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like you forgot to put it inside the [jQuery ready function](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

```
$(function(){
    $("span:contains('Error')").hide();
    $("div:contains('Access denied'):not(:has(div))").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below,

```
$(".UserGeneric span.ms-bold:contains('Error')").hide();
```

or If you want to hide the whole error then

```
$(".UserGeneric span.ms-bold:contains('Error')").parent().hide();
```